# Navie Bayes classifier in Data Mining

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

Googled a lot to find an answer.Then thought this will be the area where some one will be able to answer my doubt.

In classification algorithm we have model and prediction part.
Normally while testing we have accuracy rate.
Likewise is there any accuracy rate/confidence for model in Navie Bayes algorithm.

Comment: If by accuracy rate you mean precision (#correct/#total), then why not?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation is (usually) not part of the classifier.

It's something you do seperately to evaluate if you did a good job, or not.

If you classify your test data using naive bayes, you can perform exactly the same kind of evaluation as with other classifiers!